How to update fontawesome 5 to 6?. Renaming FontAwesome6 or using fontspec (with XeLaTeX)
For updating Font Awesome icons 5 to 6, I think may be two ways
1.- As the documentation of Font Awesome 5 package shows, downloiad the new FontAwesome6 files and renaming

Renaming files and putting in the fonts folder of MikTeX, in the fonts folder of XeLaTeX, eve in the .tex files Folder.

No success!
2.- Donwloading Font Awesome 6 Desktop (3 .OTFs files) and using
\usepackage{fontspec}

and
\newfontfamily{\fa}{Font Awesome 6}
and I tried multiple variants with newfontfamily
No success!.
MWE
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
%\usepackage[spanish]{babel}

\usepackage{fontawesome5}

\begin{document}
Jei Font awesome 5

\faAngry
\faAngry[regular]
\faMapMarker
\faMapMarker*

\faIcon{angry}

\faIcon{amazon}

%\faIcon{x-twitter}

\end{document}

And the solution is...

I would guess all you need to do is copy fontawesome5/tufontawesomefree.fd to your local directory with the document and change FontAwesome5Free-Solid-???.otf to the corresponding name for fontawesome6 (which I don't have)

I can´t reach the solution. I´m more interested in customizing the package for using Fontawesome 6 with PDFLaTeX, without using XeLaTeX or LuaLaTex.
I understand that is mandatory adding new lines for new icons in the file fontawesome5-mapping.def , similar to __fontawesome_def_icon:nnnnn{\faZhihu}{zhihu}{brands1}{199}{"F63F}

To make the font available for pdflatex would be a lot more work and can't just be done from the tex side you would need to create the subset 128 character fonts and create the tfm font metric files for them as well as setting up mapping etc. Obviously it's possible but I can't really help
